# Difference between "get' VS "getProperty"

Tags: java, properties-file

```
Properties myProp = new Properties();
myProp.put("material", "steel");

Properties prop1 = new Properties(myProp);

System.out.println(prop1.get("material") + ", " + prop1.getProperty("material"));
// outputs "null, steel"
```

Isn't get similar to getProperty in the sense that it returns the entries/attributes of
an Object? Why is it not returning 'steel' when using get?

Comment: There's a syntax error, you may want to change `props` to `prop1`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`get` is inherited from `Hashtable`, and is declared to return `Object`.

`getProperty` is introduced by `Properties`, and is declared to return `String`.

Note that`getProperty` will consult the "defaults" properties which you can pass into the constructor for `Properties`; `get` won't. In most cases they'll return the same value though. In the example you've given, you *are* using a default backing properties:

- `prop1` doesn't *directly* contain an entry for `"material"`, hence why `get` is returning null.
- `myProp` *does* contain an entry for `"material"`, so when you call `prop1.getProperty("material")`, it will find that it doesn't have it directly, and check in `myProp` instead, and find `"steel"` there.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the return type.  It only has to do with the fact that he has *only* added defaults to the second properties and no actual "first-class" properties.  So HashMap.get() will never find anything in his second Properties.

Comment: @KevinWelker: Are you denying that the return type *is a difference* between the two methods? That's all I was trying to say in the first two bits.

Comment: No, it just doesn't answer his question as to why get is returning null.

Comment: @KevinWelker: Fortunately, the final paragraph already answered that, and I've now edited it to make that clearer :)

Comment: There is an edge case, I would like to add. If the backing Map of the Properties-class holds has a property, which is not a String, the default is preferred, even if it is not set. So you can get null for a key, even if you used put with this key to add a non-null value.

Comment: Example:
Properties props = new Properties(new Properties());
props.put("key", new Object());
System.out.println(props.getProperty("key") == null); // true

Answer (score 4):

A look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) shows that `get` is inherited, and returns `Object` whereas `getProperty` is a member of `Properties` and returns the `String`.

Seemingly they should return the same, however from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) again:

> If the key is not found in this property list, the default property list, and its defaults, recursively, are then checked.

So it is best to use `getProperty` as it will return the default if it is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `Properties` object (`props` or `prop1`?), has no properties added directly to it.  It only uses `myProp` as defaults.  So those values never get added to the backing `HashMap`.  `Properties.getProperty()` doesn't find "material" in the backing HashMap so it can look in the defaults.  But the inherited `HashMap.get()` *only* looks in the backing HashMap and not in the defaults that you passed into the constructor.