# Why can't I read an Integer in my Properties file?

Tags: java, file-io, properties

I'm trying to write a configs file in Java and I put my port number inside it for my HTTP Web Server to connect to and also the root path.

Configs file:

```
root= some root
port=8020
```

I am trying to access the properties like this:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("config.txt");       
//loading properties from properties file        
config.load(file);

int port = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("port"));   
System.out.println("this is port " + port);
```

If I do it with a single parameter in the `getProperty` method, I get this error

```
"java.lang.NumberFormatException: null"
```

However, if I access it like this

`int port = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("port", "80"));`

it works.

Also, it works for `config.getProperty("root");` so I don't understand...

Edit:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Server
{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        boolean listening = true;
        ServerSocket server = null;     
        Properties config = new Properties();
        int port = 0;
        try
        {              
            //Reading properties file
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("config.txt");       
            //loading properties from properties file        
            config.load(file);

            port = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("port"));   
            System.out.println("this is port " + port);


            System.out.println("Server binding to port " + port);
            server = new ServerSocket(port);



        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found: " + e);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Server successfully binded to port " + port);

        while(listening)
        {
            System.out.println("Attempting to connect to client");
            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to client");
            new HTTPThread(client, config).start();
        }

        server.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a self contained example to reproduce your problem? I suspect when you re-examine your test you will find that the `port` was not being loaded.

Comment: OP, we're trying to help format the code (properties). Why do you revert the editions ? BTW [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) might help.

Comment: it seems that in config.txt the property "port" does not exist.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice. I noticed some mistakes so I edited it.

Comment: @JohnathanAu Put here the complete code demonstrating the correct read of root and the incorrect read of port after one load.

Comment: Is the result of the 2-Param-`getProperty` = 80 by any chance?

Comment: @JohnathanAu hey man, how did you solve this? i am having the same problem retrieving and int parameter from my confing file. It wont cast from Object to int...so i am having trouble getting my port number. thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Can you provide a self contained example to reproduce your problem?
>
> Sorry, I don't understand

When I run

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("root", "some root");
prop.setProperty("port", "8020");
prop.store(new FileWriter("config.txt"), "test");

Properties config = new Properties();
//loading properties from properties file
config.load(new FileReader("config.txt"));

int port = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("port"));
System.out.println("this is port " + port);
```

I get

```
this is port 8020
```

Comment: Do I have to explicitly setProperty in my program? I want to type inside the text file myself...

Comment: @JohnathanAu Peter just tested and found the reading part of your app itself works. You can do the same test and diff the outcome of above test and your own props-file. Maybe you find a difference causing your problem?

Comment: @JohnathanAu I did this to show how you can write a simple program which anyone can run to demonstrate there is or is not a problem.  In short, you are doing something wrong, but you don't know what it is and there isn't enough information for us to tell you what it is.  If you construct a simple, complete example you are likely to work out what the problem is yourself, if not you can post it here and we can see what the matter is.

Comment: `I want to type inside the text file myself...` In that case you need to edit the right file correctly which is what you appear to be having trouble with.

Comment: I also think there is not port property in your config.txt

Comment: I bet there is some formatting issue that prevents the port-property to be recognized by java.

Answer (score 7):

**The difference is**

```
root= some root #STRING

port=8020  #INTEGER
```

so to get the root property you can do this..

```
props.getProperty("root"); //Returns a String
```

for the integer

```
props.get("port"); //Returns a Object
```

---

**How the Java Properties class works**

```
public String getProperty(String key) {
    Object oval = super.get(key);
    String sval = (oval instanceof String) ? (String)oval : null;
    return ((sval == null) && (defaults != null)) ? defaults.getProperty(key) : sval;
    }
```

---

*//btw. Peter Lawrey is putting the port as String - thats why its works in his version.*

**READ THIS:** [difference between get & getProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104395/difference-between-get-vs-getproperty)

Answer (score 1):

```
properties.get("key) - should work for any object type - convert it later to a specific type
properties.getProperty("key") -- will always get a string regardless of a value type in the properties.
```